# What graphical git tool for Mac can show per-file history better than github?

Tags: macos, git

I want a nice graphical version of `git log -p some/file.rb` on my Mac.  Tower 1.2 boasts a new File History view, but that just shows two dropdowns with SHA1s to compare; it's slightly less useful than a MediaWiki "compare versions" history (it doesn't even show commit messages).

I can't find anything in GitNub or Gitti that does this.  GitX does it about as well as GitHub, but it leaves me wishing I could just scroll up and down to see the diffs instead of having to click each commit.  Is there a better tool?

Answer (score 3):

I would give SourceTree a try. It has a nice and powerful GUI.

Comment: The function you are looking for in SourceTree is the horribly misleading "Log Selected," you can find that by right clicking the file in question.

Comment: SourceTree is too complicated! I miss a tool like the one included in WebStorm which is very flexible and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I am used to and like how Netbeans shows file history, so I just create a project in netbeans with the option `PHP Application with Existing Sources`, now you can enjoy per file history and graphical diff of each commit, like so:

1. Locate your file in projects pane, on the left
2. Right click > Git > Show History
3. Choose `Diff` From 2 buttons on the left, `Summary` and `Diff`
4. Now tap each commit